# How to receive feeds from database as newfeeds in Facebook?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to make my webPage in mvc feel with new records added in specific table in database
and show this feeds as facebook. If I make trigger in db to fire when row inserted or updated how it send values automatically to my webpage.

Comment: have you looked into RSS

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) along with a good [example](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/11/introduction-ksigdo-knockout-signalr-to.html)

Comment: thanks alot ,and i need simple example of making signalr from 0 to have deep understand of it

Comment: did you see the example I linked? Here is [another](http://geekswithblogs.net/jeroenb/archive/2011/12/14/signalr-starter-application.aspx) with a link to download at the end